# Trying to open Div after passing selected value to url. (closing after reload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to open a div within my Jsp page, so what i am doing is passing an Id to the url, the url does some background work in my controller and retrieves the data as expected, this is all working fine. What I want to do is only show the div once the data is loaded. When I load the page no option is selected so no data is retrieved, when the user picks a option I want to load the url and open the div and keep open, I have tried loads and noting seems to be working as i like.  here is where I am at know.

```js
$("#vehicleSelected").on('change',function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("vehicleInfo");
    if (x.style.display === 'none'){
     x.style.display ='block';
     console.log("made it" + x);
    }else{
     x.style.display='none';
     console.log("made it not" + x);

    }

     

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  Welcome: <strong><c:out value="${username}"></c:out></strong> <select
   data-toggle="dropdown" id="vehicleSelected"
   onchange=" window.location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath }/driver/'+this.value ">
   <option>Select Vehicle</option>
   <c:forEach var="vehicles" items="${vehicles }">
    <option value="${vehicles.id }">
     <c:out value="${vehicles.vehicle_name }"></c:out></option>

   </c:forEach>
  </select>
  <div class="panel panel-info ">

   <div class="panel-heading text-center">

    <h4>Driver Vehicle Inspection Form</h4>

    <div id="vehicleInfo" style="display:none;">
     <span>Vehicle:<strong><c:out
        value="${vehicleById.make }"></c:out>, <c:out
        value="${vehicleById.model }"></c:out></strong>
     </span><br> <span>VIN:<strong><c:out
        value="${vehicleById.chassis_number }"></c:out></strong></span><br> <span>
      Registration:<strong><c:out value="${vehicleById.plate }"></c:out></strong>
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

I have also tried putting this all into a method and using return false; still did not work, any ideas what i could do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching high and low for a solution, I had to take a slightly different route and check the URL for the id and if present show the div, this is not what I wanted but works, and I am posting this for anyone that might stumble on the question and find this method helpful.  below is the solution that works for know.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    var url = window.location.href;

    var urlEnd = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    if (urlEnd !== "") {
        $("#vehicleInfo").show();

    }

});
```